# How to show results in text, not digits

Tags: max, min

I'm new to programming so forgive me if my question is vague.
I'm creating program that tells you which one of a triangle, circle or square has the largest area. I want the program to say "The triangle has the largest area", and not showing me the area in digits.

I know how to show which of the numbers was largest but how can I make the program say "the triangle" or "the square" has the largest area?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Nice that you want to learn programming. Your question is a bit unclear.. what programming language are you using and what's your current code? I mean.. you probably already coded something, don't you? I recommend reading [How to ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: How do you think we should answer this question without even a note about the programming language you want to use? Also, a question requires a minimum sample of your code.